# shell command # can't be carry out when it not used for comments on colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, magic-string

I'm confused about this code! Why # cant't play a role that takes the length of a string?

```
 string="abcd"

 !echo ${#string}
```

In fact, the code behind # has become commented and cannot be executed!

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This works correctly, but you cannot mix python and bash variables in this way. Try this instead:

```
!string="abcd" && echo ${#string}
```

The two statements have to be on the same line because in IPython, each `!` statement opens a temporary subshell and variables are not persisted between shells. If you want to use multiline bash programs, you can use the `%%bash` cell magic instead:

```
%%bash
string="abcd"
echo  ${#string}
```

Comment: OK, I got it! Tks for your patience.